# Get all rows display with same value in column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT auction_id, account_no, branch_address
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.`aul_id` = Table2.`aul_id`
WHERE Table2.`date` = '2018-03-20'
GROUP BY Table1.`branch_address`
HAVING Count(*) >= '10' AND Count(*) <= '10'
```

But this returns only 1 record of each where it should return 10

Comment: Same as `HAVING Count(*) = '10'`...

Comment: That group by is invalid. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: That LEFT JOIN executes as an INNER JOIN. To get true LEFT JOIN result, move the table2 condition from WHERE to ON.

Comment: I have multiple condition on Where so how to move to ON ?

Comment: Use `AND` in the ON clause.

Comment: [`COUNT(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) returns a number. You compare it with a string (`'10'`). You can get unexpected results. Don't use strings instead of numbers.

Comment: My query is working But what I want columns with address matching with count 10 or something else which is dynamic so if address1 is comming 10 times in table then it should return 10 rows but due to group by it is returning 1 row

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   auction_id,
   account_no,
   branch_address 
FROM
   Table1 
   LEFT JOIN
      Table2 
      ON Table1.`aul_id` = Table2.`aul_id` 
WHERE
   Table2.`date` = '2018-03-20' 
   AND Table1.`branch_address` IN 
   (
      SELECT
         Table1.`branch_address` 
      FROM
         Table1 
         LEFT JOIN
            Table2 
            ON Table1.`aul_id` = Table2.`aul_id` 
      WHERE
         Table2.`date` = '2018-03-20' 
      GROUP BY
         Table1.`branch_address` 
      HAVING
         Count(*) >= '10' 
         AND Count(*) <= '10' 
   )
```

Comment: `Count(*) >= '10' AND Count(*) <= '10'` can be `Count(*) = '10'`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query without having clause and check the count(*) value.

You will get some answer. Sample oracle query has been added below.

------------------------------------------CODE-------------------------------

```
create table table1(branchaddress varchar2(10), aul_id number);
insert into table1 values('address1', 10);
insert into table1 values('address1', 10);
insert into table1 values('address2', 10);
insert into table1 values('address2', 10);
create table table2(branchaddress varchar2(10),aul_id number );
insert into table2 values('address1', 10);
insert into table2 values('address2', 10);

commit;

SELECT table1.branchaddress, count(*)
FROM Table1, table2
where Table1.branchaddress = Table2.branchaddress(+)
GROUP BY Table1.branchaddress
HAVING Count(*) >= 2 AND Count(*) <= 10
```

---